# Different time_lengths for interval, duration and period

Tags: r, lubridate

I am new to `lubridate`. I tried to calculate the difference between two sets of time with `lubridate` but get slight different answers for interval, duration, and period

```
library(lubridate)
a <- dmy_hms("9/7/1988 4:30:00")
b <- dmy_hms("2/11/2019 4:30:00")

c <- a %--% b

per <- as.period(c)
dur <- as.duration(c)

time_length(c, unit = "year") #31.31694
time_length(per, unit = "year") #31.33716
time_length(dur, unit = "year") #31.33699
```

Comment: Unrelated to the problem at hand: Don't use `c` as a variable name. Does not save time and is not a very intuitive name but might make debugging harder since it masks `c`.

Comment: You can see this in the docs: **Durations are exact time measurements, whereas periods are relative time measurements.** So duration != period and hence the time lengths will differ,

Answer (score 0):

As explained in the documentation for `as.duration` available via `?as.duration`, `as.duration` will return the **exact** time measurements while `as.period` will provide **relative** measurements. It goes on to state that:

> Hence, a one to one mapping does not exist between durations and periods. When used with a period object, as.duration provides an inexact estimate of the length of the period;

Therefore, using `time_length` will result in different results for `as.period` and `as.duration`.

This is also further expanded on in the documentation for `time_length`,**intervals are just not equivalent to durations**.

To get the same result for `%--%` and `as.period`, first convert periods to intervals as follows:

```
res <- a %--% b
 dur <- as.duration(res)
 per <- as.period(res)
time_length(as.interval(per,a), "year")
[1] 31.31694
 time_length(res,"year") 
[1] 31.31694
```